# Check for librt linking

Tags: gcc, conditional-compilation, librt

Is there a macro that I can `#ifdef` for to check if librt has been linked to, ie by `-lrt` with gcc?

Comment: Could you explain why you need that? (The pre-processor generally doesn't have a clue about linker stuff, it runs way before linking is even considered.)

Comment: I was putting together a folder of functions I commonly use and don't want to have to keep writing. One of the functions in the timing file depends on `librt` and so causes compilation to fail if that file is included without linking to `librt` even if that function is not called.

Comment: That's something you need to deal with in your build system, not in the source code. If someone just compiles (and doesn't link yet) that file, there will be no linker flags at all and that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I see. I don't actually have a "build system". I've just created a bash alias for g++ to include a directory of my header files in the `#include` search.

Comment: @chewsocks, then your `.bash_profile` *is* your build system ;-).

Comment: @chewsocks, so in your buildsystem, just replace `-lrt` with `-DI_WANT_LIBRT -lrt` and there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, gcc doesn't have such macro (I've dumped preprocessor macros to check). On Windows with Microsoft compiler you can use `_VC_NODEFAULTLIB` macro to detect builds without `libc` reference.

Comment: Thank you for checking. Can you show how you dumped the preprocessor macros so I (and others) can do it in the future?